# Is there some way to implement automatic TimeSeries extrapolation or series continuation?

Tags: expression-manipulation, time-series

I am working with a large number of `TimeSeries` of irregular length. This means that if I sum them, or compute the mean, it cuts off at the terminus of the shortest series. Is there a convenient way to make it compute to the end of the longest series, assuming that the missing data did not change?

For example, given

```
test1 = TimeSeries[{{{2000, 1, 1}, 1}, {{2001, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2002, 1, 1}, 3}}];
test2 = TimeSeries[{{{2000, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2001, 1, 1}, 2}}];
```

*Mathematica*  computes `Mean[{test1, test2}]["Values"]` to be `{1.5, 2}`. I would prefer to get `{1.5, 2, 2.5}`.

What is a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Extrapolating the data in your 2nd example as flat seems reasonable for that toy example, but what reason do you have for believing that will always be a good way to go?

Comment: `Mean[{ArrayPad[test2["Values"], {0, 1}, "Fixed"], test1["Values"]}]`?

Comment: @m_goldberg For my data, it's better than omitting these dates entirely.

Comment: @Algohi Interesting, but perhaps inelegant given that different members of the list fall short by different numbers of dates.

Comment: Try `TimeSeriesThread[Mean, {test1, test2}]["Values"]`. You can play around with the `ResamplingMethod` for each time series to have more control over the result.

Comment: @AndyRoss the docs only reveal "Interpolation" as a possible method so while you could play around with the interpolation order (and are there any other additional options available for the interpolation resampling method ..the docs imply there are) what other methods are available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer to this is to use `TimeSeriesThread` which will perform the extrapolation you are after (though it will rightly complain about extrapolating).

```
test1 = TimeSeries[{{{2000, 1, 1}, 1}, {{2001, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2002, 1, 1}, 3}}];
test2 = TimeSeries[{{{2000, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2001, 1, 1}, 2}}];

TimeSeriesThread[Mean, {test1, test2}]["Values"]

(* {3/2, 2, 5/2} *)
```

If you want finer control over the extrapolation you can set the `ResamplingMethod` on each `TimeSeries` object. The documentation is pretty thin on options. Currently the only documented possibilities are to either use a constant or to set interpolation options. By default, linear interpolation is used for `TimeSeries`.

In your case, using a constant makes sense and doesn't complain about extrapolation.

```
test1 = TimeSeries[{{{2000, 1, 1}, 1}, {{2001, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2002, 1, 1}, 3}}, 
                ResamplingMethod -> {"Constant", 3}];

test2 = TimeSeries[{{{2000, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2001, 1, 1}, 2}}, 
                ResamplingMethod -> {"Constant", 2}];

TimeSeriesThread[Mean, {test1, test2}]["Values"]

(* {3/2, 2, 5/2} *)
```

You can also set various interpolation options. In fact, you can use any valid option setting for `Interpolation`. For example, say you wanted to do zero order interpolation.

```
m = {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0};

test1 = TimeSeries[{{{2000, 1, 1}, 1}, {{2001, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2002, 1, 1}, 3}}, 
              ResamplingMethod -> m];

test2 = TimeSeries[{{{2000, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2001, 1, 1}, 2}}, 
              ResamplingMethod -> m];

TimeSeriesThread[Mean, {test1, test2}]["Values"]

(* {3/2, 2, 5/2} *)
```

Finally, you can create your own resampling method. *The usual warnings apply here since this is undocumented functionality and is subject to change*.

`ResamplingMethod` can be given as a function that takes the `TemporalData` object (`TimeSeries` is a special case) and returns a list of `Listable` functions, one for each path, that return a value given a time or list of times. These are what is returned by the "PathFunctions" property of `TemporalData`.

Suppose we want to do linear interpolation for values in the range of the `TimeSeries` and then give the last value for all times beyond the `TimeSeries`. We can create a function that does this as such.

```
f[ts_TemporalData] := Block[{fns, mxs, vs},
  fns = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ ts["Paths"];
  mxs = Max /@ ts["ValueList"];
  vs = Last /@ ts["ValueList"];
  MapThread[
   Function[\[FormalX], 
     Piecewise[{{#1[\[FormalX]], \[FormalX] <= #2}}, #3], 
     Listable] &, {fns, mxs, vs}]
  ]
```

Now we can use this function for the `ResamplingMethod`.

```
test1 = TimeSeries[{{{2000, 1, 1}, 1}, {{2001, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2002, 1, 1},3}}, 
             ResamplingMethod -> f];

test2 = TimeSeries[{{{2000, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2001, 1, 1}, 2}}, 
             ResamplingMethod -> f];

TimeSeriesThread[Mean, {test1, test2}]["Values"]

(*{3/2, 2, 5/2}*)
```

Obviously this is messy, which is probably why it isn't documented, but it could certainly be useful.

Comment: @Mike Honeychurch hopefully this answers your question

Comment: yes thanks for this information. cheers

Comment: Using a function for ResamplingMethod is quite convenient, however, at least on MMA 11.1 and 11.2 the resulting time series does not work with any function that tries to retrieve the path function, including TimeSeriesResample. test1["PathFunction"] results in the error message: Path function failed to be created with the current setting of ResamplingMethod option. I suspect this is another reason why this is not documented.